# Can you stack Eldritch Knight's War Magic ability with Bladesinger's Extra Attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, wizard, stacking, eldritch-knight

Let's say I am playing a 13th level character, 6 levels Bladesinger Wizard, 7 levels Eldritch Knight Fighter. I would have access to these abilities in question:

**War Magic**:

> Beginning at 7th level, when you use your action to cast a cantrip, you can make one weapon attack as a bonus action.

Bladesinger's **Extra Attack**:

> Starting at 6th level, you can attack twice, instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action on your turn. Moreover, you can cast one of your cantrips in place of one of those attacks.

With these rules in mind, is it viable to take the attack action, cast Booming Blade and make one weapon attack, and then because I cast a cantrip, also make another weapon attack with my bonus action?

Comment: Welcome to the stack Josbar, take the [tour] when you have a moment. I've closed this as a duplicate, as it has been asked before. Don't worry, duplicates are okay, they can help future readers find the answers they are looking for.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov got my hopes up that i could help a newbie out and actually answer, oh well

Answer (score 1):

### Technically, I would say No

The reason being the Eldritch Knight feature says "when you use your *action* to cast a cantrip".

And when you use the Bladesinger Extra Attack feature, you are using your action to attack (the Attack Action), not cast the spell. Even though though you can replace one of your attacks (lower case 'a') with the cantrip!

Its a subtle distinction but I believe by RAW that means your combo doesn't work.

(I wouldn't be averse to a DM allowing it anyway)

Answer (score -1):

The D&D 5e PHB(pg. 164), regarding rules of multiclassing, states:

> #### Extra Attack
>
> "If you gain the **Extra Attack** feature from more than one class, the features don't add together. You can't make more than one attack **using this feature** unless it says you do."

With just this note, it seems that it could work, since War Magic is not **Extra Attack**. Moreover, the Eldritch Knight's **War Magic** feature notes that

> "When you use your action **to cast a cantrip**, you  can make a weapon attack as a bonus action."

Bladesinger's version of **Extra Attack** obviously doesn't stack with Fighter's, but its note that...

> "You can attack twice, instead of once, whenever you take the **Attack action** on your turn"

...seems to not allow it.

**RAW, it does not work.** If you think RAW is stupid, have this discussion with your DM. We aren't the end-all-be-all's of TTRPGs, have your fun!

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following your argument here. **War Magic** is *not* the **Extra Attack** feature, so I'm not seeing the relevance of a rule restricting specifically the **Extra Attack** feature.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I think I was trying to say, "This could work cause you aren't trying to stack extra attacks, you're stacking war magic and extra attack which happens to give you 3 attacks, one being a cantrip"

Comment: Hmm I may have read your answer backwards then.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov: You're not alone. This reads like it's leading up to a "This works" summary, then flips it at the very end with no clear justification I can see.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Why bother with the downvote? It's an answer on a duplicate question that is already answered elsewhere!

Comment: @wheatleycrab: I wasn't the down-voter (haven't cast any votes on anything here save a tick up for Thomas's first comment); activity does draw attention though, which may have drawn the down-vote. It would help if you made the answer's arguments actually lead to its conclusions.